# Iterators in sets in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, set, max

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
using namespace std;

set <int> arr;

int main() {
int n, m, tmp;
cin>>n>>m;
for (int i=1; i<=m+n; i++) {
    cin>>tmp;
    if (tmp!=-1) arr.insert(tmp);
    else {
        set<int>::iterator it;
        it=arr.begin();
        cout<<*it<<endl;
        arr.erase(arr.begin());
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

So this program actually outputs the smallest element present in the set. But when I replace `arr.begin()` with `arr.end()` I don't get the largest element. I need help in understanding what is happening and what should I do to output the largest number in the set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `end` iterator is not actually inside the container, but "points" to one place *beyond* the end of the container. Dereferencing an iterator outside of the container leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

Pretend you have the array

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Remembering that array indexes are zero-based, the valid indexes for the above array would be `0` to `3` (inclusive). The "begin" iterator for the array would be `&a[0]` and the "end" iterator would be `&a[4]`.

Or graphically it would be something like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
^               ^
|               |
begin           end
```

If using reverse iterators (with [`std::set::rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/rbegin) and [`std::set::rend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/rbegin)) then it would be something like this:

```
    +---+---+---+---+
    | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
    +---+---+---+---+
^               ^
|               |
rend            rbegin
```

Answer (score 2):

> But when I replace `arr.begin()` with `arr.end()` I don't get the largest element.

That's because `end()` "points to" one element past the last element of the set.

> what should I do to output the largest number in the set

You need [`arr.rbegin()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/rbegin/), which points to the first element from the other end, i.e. to the last element proper. The type is going to change from `set<int>::iterator` to `set<int>::reverse_iterator`. If you use C++11, using `auto` instead of the explicit type would help you hide the change in the type.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::set::rbegin`.

```
            set<int>::reverse_iterator it=arr.rbegin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing `std::set::end()` results in undefined behaviour.

If you want the greatest element, assuming standard ordering using `less<int>`, use `rbegin()`.